# Passing interface variable through a class constructor in C#

Tags: c#, oop, object, constructor, interface

I'm practicing C# on [Testdome.com](https://www.testdome.com/d/c-sharp-interview-questions/18), I solved the coding exercise (AlertService) below but still not convinced by the purpose of point 3 and 4:

Refactor the AlertService and AlertDAO classes:

1- Create a new interface, named IAlertDAO, that contains the same methods as AlertDAO.

2- AlertDAO should implement the IAlertDAO interface.

**3- AlertService should have a constructor that accepts IAlertDAO.**

**4- The RaiseAlert and GetAlertTime methods should use the object passed through the constructor.**

This is the code I write, I added the **constructor** and the **interface** that **AlertDAO** implements, at the end The Compilation was OK but I need to know if this is the right way to solve it:

```
public class AlertService   
{
    private readonly AlertDAO storage = new AlertDAO();

    //Constructor
    public AlertService(IAlertDAO alert)
    {
        storage = (AlertDAO)alert;
    }

    public Guid RaiseAlert()
    {
        return this.storage.AddAlert(DateTime.Now);
    }

    public DateTime GetAlertTime(Guid id)
    {
        return this.storage.GetAlert(id);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAlertDAO alertDao = new AlertDAO();
        AlertService alert = new AlertService(alertDao);
        Guid id = alert.RaiseAlert();
        Console.WriteLine(alert.GetAlertTime(id));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class AlertDAO : IAlertDAO
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, DateTime> alerts = new Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>();

    public Guid AddAlert(DateTime time)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.alerts.Add(id, time);
        return id;
    }

    public DateTime GetAlert(Guid id)
    {
        return this.alerts[id];
    }   
}

public interface IAlertDAO
{
    Guid AddAlert(DateTime time);
    DateTime GetAlert(Guid id);
}
```

Comment: The ctor for AlertService doesn't make sense. Why pass an interface if it's cast to a concrete class anyway? The backing field (`storage`) should be declared with `IAlertDAO` as well. Also, what is the main method doing there? It has no business being in a class dedicated to something else entirely.

Comment: Change your storage Variable to IAlertDAO also, and you are fine. The cast is crashing the idea of the use of an interface.

Comment: @lennart I added that constructor because it's asked to in point 3 and 4

Comment: @WalidGhodhbani I think his point was to not cast the interface to a specific type. Instead declare `storage` as an `IAlertDAO`.

Comment: @WalidGhodhbani If you do as Rufus suggests then you (or anyone else) can make a different class that implements IAlertDAO at any time and pass that into the constructor instead.  This is the basis of dependency injection with inversion of control, which is very useful when you need it, but appears pointless when you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things others have pointed out. `storage` should be of type `IAlertDAO`, so there is no need to cast in your constructor. No need to `new` it up in its declaration.

```
public class AlertService   
{
    private readonly IAlertDAO storage;

    //Constructor
    public AlertService(IAlertDAO alert)
    {
        storage = alert;
    }

    public Guid RaiseAlert()
    {
        return this.storage.AddAlert(DateTime.Now);
    }

    public DateTime GetAlertTime(Guid id)
    {
        return this.storage.GetAlert(id);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAlertDAO alertDao = new AlertDAO();
        AlertService alert = new AlertService(alertDao);
        Guid id = alert.RaiseAlert();
        Console.WriteLine(alert.GetAlertTime(id));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class AlertDAO : IAlertDAO
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, DateTime> alerts = new Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>();

    public Guid AddAlert(DateTime time)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.alerts.Add(id, time);
        return id;
    }

    public DateTime GetAlert(Guid id)
    {
        return this.alerts[id];
    }   
}

public interface IAlertDAO
{
    Guid AddAlert(DateTime time);
    DateTime GetAlert(Guid id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost right, but you need to change `storage` variable to `IAlerDAO`. It's needed to follow one of principles in OOP ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

See [Dependency Injection](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/dependency-injection-design-pattern-csharp/)

TL;DR: it allows you to decouple your service from actual implementation of data access layer, so, you can pass another implementation of interface, which stores the data to different place. Or you can create unit tests by creating 'dumb' implementation, which stores data in memory instead of read DB (you do not need to rely on DB status).